# C# wpf failed to create an instance of custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

They say, A Picture is Worth a Thousand Words.

I have a custom control called `RichTextBoxEditor`:

[image]

Here is the XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfRichText.Ex.Controls.RichTextEditor" x:Name="uxRichTextEditor"    
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:asis="clr-namespace:WpfRichText.Ex.AttachedProperties">

<Grid >

    <!-- Set the styles for the tool bar. -->
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="formatTextStyle">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Palatino Linotype"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value ="14"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="CommandTarget" Value="{Binding ElementName=mainRTB}"></Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" x:Key="formatTextStyle2">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Palatino Linotype"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value ="14"></Setter>
            <!--<Setter Property="CommandTarget" Value="{Binding ElementName=mainRTB}"></Setter>-->
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="formatImageStyle">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"></Setter>
            <!--<Setter Property="CommandTarget" Value="{Binding ElementName=mainRTB}"></Setter>-->
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <DockPanel Name="mainPanel">

        <!-- This tool bar contains all the editing buttons. -->
        <ToolBar Height="30" DockPanel.Dock="Top" ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource formatTextStyle}" Command="EditingCommands.ToggleBold" ToolTip="Bold">
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">B</TextBlock>
            </Button>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource formatTextStyle}" Command="EditingCommands.ToggleItalic" ToolTip="Italic">
                <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold">I</TextBlock>
            </Button>

            <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource formatTextStyle2}" x:Name="ToolStripButtonStrikeout" ToolTip="Strikethrough" Click="ToolStripButtonStrikeout_Click" Foreground="Black" Width="19" Height="19">
                <ToggleButton.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Strikeout.png"/>
                </ToggleButton.Background>
            </ToggleButton>

            <Button x:Name="Tool_Link" Style="{StaticResource formatImageStyle}" ToolTip="Link" Click="Tool_Link_Click" Width="30" Height="19">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Link.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="Tool_Spoiler" Style="{StaticResource formatImageStyle}" ToolTip="Spoiler" Width="30" Height="19">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Spoiler.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>

            <Button x:Name="Tool_Image" Style="{StaticResource formatImageStyle}" ToolTip="Image" Height="19">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Images.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="Tool_Video" Style="{StaticResource formatImageStyle}" ToolTip="Youtube video" Margin="0,1,0,-1" Height="19">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Video.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="Tool_ALeft" Style="{StaticResource formatImageStyle}" ToolTip="Align Left" Height="19" Width="30">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/paragraphleftjustify.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                </Button.Background>

            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="Tool_ACenter" Style="{StaticResource formatImageStyle}" ToolTip="Align Center" Height="19">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/paragraphcenterjustify.png"/>
                </Button.Background>

            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="Tool_Header" Style="{StaticResource formatImageStyle}" ToolTip="Header" Height="19">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/charactergrowfont.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="Tool_Quote" Style="{StaticResource formatImageStyle}" ToolTip="Quote" Height="19">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/quote.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="Tool_Code" Style="{StaticResource formatImageStyle}" ToolTip="Decrease Indent" Height="19">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/code.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
        </ToolBar>

        <StackPanel >
            <RichTextBox Name="mainRTB" AcceptsTab="True"  Height="160"
                         asis:RichTextboxAssistant.BoundDocument="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=uxRichTextEditor}"
                         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  Width="365" />
            <!--<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=uxRichTextEditor}" Height="25" />-->
        </StackPanel>

    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

This control originally was taken from the net, which i forgot where it is. But then i modified some component of it. It was fine while in Designer, but when i put it on the main window, it will look like this:
[image]

Here is some information that may useful:

[image]

Thanks in Advance :)

**EDIT:**

Here is the original XAML:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:RTFEditor="clr-namespace:RTFEditor"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="RTFEditor.RTFBox"
x:Name="RTFEditor"    
d:DesignWidth="600" d:DesignHeight="600" Loaded="RTFEditor_Loaded">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="FontListKlasse" d:IsDataSource="True" ObjectType="{x:Type RTFEditor:FontList}"/>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="FontHeightKlasse" d:IsDataSource="True" ObjectType="{x:Type RTFEditor:FontHeight}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>   

<DockPanel>
    <ToolBar x:Name="ToolBarOben" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Button x:Name="ToolStripButtonOpen" Click="ToolStripButtonOpen_Click">
            <Image Source="Images\Open.png" Stretch="None"/>                
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="ToolStripButtonPrint" Click="ToolStripButtonPrint_Click">
            <Image Source="Images\Print.png" Stretch="None"/>               
        </Button>
        <Separator/>
        <Button x:Name="ToolStripButtonCut" Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" ToolTip="Cut">
            <Image Source="Images\Cut.png" Stretch="None"/>             
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="ToolStripButtonCopy" Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" ToolTip="Copy">
            <Image Source="Images\Copy.png" Stretch="None"/>                
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="ToolStripButtonPaste" Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" ToolTip="Paste">
            <Image Source="Images\Paste.png" Stretch="None"/>               
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="ToolStripButtonUndo" Command="ApplicationCommands.Undo" ToolTip="Undo">
            <Image Source="Images\Undo.png" Stretch="None"/>                
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="ToolStripButtonRedo" Command="ApplicationCommands.Redo" ToolTip="Redo">
            <Image Source="Images\Redo.png" Stretch="None"/>                
        </Button>
        <Separator/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="Fonttype" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource FontListKlasse}}" DropDownClosed="Fonttype_DropDownClosed" />
        <ComboBox x:Name="Fontheight" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource FontHeightKlasse}}"  DropDownClosed="Fontheight_DropDownClosed" />
    </ToolBar>
    <ToolBar x:Name="ToolBarUnten" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <ToggleButton x:Name="ToolStripButtonBold" Command="EditingCommands.ToggleBold" ToolTip="Bold">
            <Image Source="Images\Bold.png" Stretch="None"/>                
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="ToolStripButtonItalic" Command="EditingCommands.ToggleItalic" ToolTip="Italic">
            <Image Source="Images\Italic.png" Stretch="None"/>              
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="ToolStripButtonUnderline" Command="EditingCommands.ToggleUnderline" ToolTip="Underline">
            <Image Source="Images\Underline.png" Stretch="None"/>               
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="ToolStripButtonStrikeout" ToolTip="Strikeout" Click="ToolStripButtonStrikeout_Click">
            <Image Source="Images\Strikeout.png" Stretch="None"/>               
        </ToggleButton>
        <Separator/>
        <Button x:Name="ToolStripButtonTextcolor" Click="ToolStripButtonTextcolor_Click">
            <Image Source="Images\Textcolor.png" Stretch="None"/>               
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="ToolStripButtonBackcolor" Click="ToolStripButtonBackcolor_Click">
            <Image Source="Images\Backcolor.png" Stretch="None"/>               
        </Button>
        <Separator/>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="ToolStripButtonAlignLeft" Command="EditingCommands.AlignLeft" ToolTip="Align Left" Click="ToolStripButtonAlignLeft_Click">
            <Image Source="Images\AlignLeft.png" Stretch="None"/>               
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="ToolStripButtonAlignCenter" Command="EditingCommands.AlignCenter" ToolTip="Align Center" Click="ToolStripButtonAlignCenter_Click">
            <Image Source="Images\AlignCenter.png" Stretch="None"/>             
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="ToolStripButtonAlignRight" Command="EditingCommands.AlignRight" ToolTip="Align Right" Click="ToolStripButtonAlignRight_Click">
            <Image Source="Images\AlignRight.png" Stretch="None"/>              
        </ToggleButton>
        <Separator/>
        <Button x:Name="ToolStripButtonBulletList" Command="EditingCommands.ToggleBullets" ToolTip="Bullets">
            <Image Source="Images\BulletList.png" Stretch="None"/>              
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="ToolStripButtonNumbersList" Command="EditingCommands.ToggleNumbering" ToolTip="Numbers">
            <Image Source="Images\NumbersList.png" Stretch="None"/>             
        </Button>
        <Separator/>
        <Button x:Name="ToolStripButtonIndent" Command="EditingCommands.IncreaseIndentation" ToolTip="Increase Indent">
            <Image Source="Images\Indent.png" Stretch="None"/>              
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="ToolStripButtonIndentDelete" Command="EditingCommands.DecreaseIndentation" ToolTip="Decrease Indent">
            <Image Source="Images\IndentRemove.png" Stretch="None"/>                
        </Button>
        <Separator/>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="ToolStripButtonSubscript" ToolTip="Subscript" Click="ToolStripButtonSubscript_Click">
            <Image Source="Images\Subscript.png" Stretch="None"/>               
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="ToolStripButtonSuperscript" ToolTip="Superscript" Click="ToolStripButtonSuperscript_Click">
            <Image Source="Images\Superscript.png" Stretch="None"/>             
        </ToggleButton>
    </ToolBar>
    <StatusBar x:Name="StatusBar" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <StatusBarItem>
            <Label x:Name="LabelZeileNr" Content="ZeileNr" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" />
        </StatusBarItem>
        <StatusBarItem >
            <Label x:Name="LabelSpalteNr" Content="SpalteNr" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
        <StatusBarItem>
            <Label x:Name="LabelEinfg" Content="Einfg" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" />
        </StatusBarItem>
        <StatusBarItem DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="100">
            <Slider x:Name="SliderZoom" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Ticks="1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10" Value="1" Delay="100" Interval="5" TickPlacement="BottomRight" Minimum="1" Maximum="10" ValueChanged="SliderZoom_ValueChanged" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" />
        </StatusBarItem>                        
    </StatusBar>
    <RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextControl" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" SelectionChanged="RichTextControl_SelectionChanged" TextChanged="RichTextControl_TextChanged" KeyDown="RichTextControl_KeyDown" KeyUp="RichTextControl_KeyUp" />        
</DockPanel>
```

**EDIT 2nd:**

If im not mistaken here is what i have done:

- Added my custom images to the project resource (Linked at compile; Resource)
- Changed the source of the image of each button (Except Bold & Italic)
- I will update this section if i remember anything else!

More Info:

I tried to copy-paste the original XAML without modifying it. When i use it in the main window, it works! But, all images of the buttons are not showing (except Bold and Italic since they dont use any image).

**RichTextEditor.xaml.cs :**

```
namespace WpfRichText.Ex.Controls
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for BindableRichTextbox.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class RichTextEditor : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(RichTextEditor),
      new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public RichTextEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return GetValue(TextProperty) as string; }
        set { 
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private void ToolStripButtonStrikeout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextRange range = new TextRange(mainRTB.Selection.Start, mainRTB.Selection.End);

        TextDecorationCollection tdc = (TextDecorationCollection)mainRTB.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty);
        if (tdc == null || !tdc.Equals(TextDecorations.Strikethrough))
        {
            tdc = TextDecorations.Strikethrough;

        }
        else
        {
            tdc = new TextDecorationCollection();
        }
        range.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, tdc);
    }

    private void Tool_Link_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you remember what you modified? Did you try changing it back then modifying smaller pieces to see when it failed?

Comment: Have you tried to google for exact error message? "Provide value on blablabla ..." one? You may get lots of hints of what is wrong this way.

Comment: @JarrettRobertson SOmehow i found the original XAML, it was on CodeProject lol. Edited the main post.